# How to write hindi text over png/jpeg image?

Tags: php, image-processing, emoji, imagettftext, image-text

i want write hindi text with emoji over image please help to solve out this

> हमारी बराबरी  English

i want write above text on 500*600 png/jpeg image.here is the code which i tried

```
function screen1(){

    $image_1 = imagecreatefromjpeg("Slice/$this->folder_number/screen-1-bg.png");

    imagealphablending($image_1, true);
    imagesavealpha($image_1, true);

     //fonting

     $white = imagecolorallocate($image_1, 255, 255, 255);
     $grey = imagecolorallocate($image_1, 128, 128, 128);
     $black = imagecolorallocate($image_1, 0, 0, 0);

     $text = 'हमारी बराबरी  English';
     $font = ('Slice/font/hindi-font');
     imagettftext($image_1, 23, 0, 161, 413, $grey, $font, $text);
     imagettftext($image_1, 30, 0, 160, 434, $white, $font, $text);


    imagepng($image_1, "Slice/$this->folder_number/output/screen-1.png");
}
```

Comment: Is the font you're using UTF-8?

Comment: yes i'm using that

Comment: What's happening when you run this code? Any errors? Also make double sure your font is UTF-8 because having font named `hindi-font` is suspiciously language specific while UTF-8 fonts have characters from all languages.

Comment: yes hindi text comes fine but emoji comes in square box.

Comment: Then most likely your font doesn't have emojis in it . Try using Arial to see if that works.

Comment: In arial i tried now hindi text also comes like emoji square. :(

Comment: I suggest you find yourself a decent unicode font then. One that includes all unicode characters. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts for a list and details